# Failed al realizar Fetch a servicio localhost

Tags: javascript

Cree un pequeño servicio, el cual retorna una lista de usuarios. Lo quiero implementar en una app, estoy obteniendo error al realizar el fetch.

```js
const url= 'http://localhost:4000/api/users'
export const obtenerClientes = async() => {
    try {
        const resultado = await fetch(url);
        const clientes = await resultado.json();
        return clientes;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Metodo actualizarCliente

```
export const actualizarCliente = async cliente =>{
console.log(cliente)
try {
    await fetch(`${URL}/edit/${cliente.id}`,{
        method:'PUT',
        body:JSON.stringify(cliente),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    });
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

}

Comment: Podrias compartir cómo estas usando `obtenerClientes`

Comment: Pude resolver el problema de ese metodo agregando en el servidor cors al utilizar express, pero ahora tengo el mismo problema con otra funcion. Actualice el post